# PropertyChanged not firing

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, inotifypropertychanged

I have a strange situation:

in a .NET CF project there is a class (call it A) which has the following structure:

```
public partial class A: Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
//for simplicity stripping off everything unrelated to this problem

        private int _SelectedRowsCount = 0;
        public int SelectedRowsCount
        {
            get { return _SelectedRowsCount; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedRowsCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRowsCount");
            }
        }

        public bool enableCollectionButton
        {
            get { return SelectedRowsCount > 0; }
        }

//....
//
//


         void SomeMethod()
{
 //for simplicity:
SelectedRowsCount = 1; //<- HERE NOT FIRING Propertychanged for enableCollectionButton
}
}
```

The class implements correctly the INotifyPropertyChanged interface which makes the  the SelectedRowsCount property to fire a property changed notification (i evaluated this with the debugger). 
The enableCollectionButton property is databound to some control like so:

```
someButton.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", this, "enableCollectionButton");
```

But the enableCollectionButton property does not change (though depending on the value of SelectedRowsCount). This property should be evaluated on a change of the SelectedRowsCount  property, BUT IS NOT!!!

Why is this not functioning, what do i miss??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class A: Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
//for simplicity stripping off everything unrelated to this problem

    private int _SelectedRowsCount = 0;
    public int SelectedRowsCount
    {
        get { return _SelectedRowsCount; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedRowsCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRowsCount");
            OnPropertyChanged("enableCollectionButton"); //This changes too !
        }
    }

    public bool enableCollectionButton
    {
        get { return SelectedRowsCount > 0; }
    }
}
```

What happens is that you're binding to the `enableCollectionButton` property, but you're not notifying the BindingManager of the change to `enableCollectionButton`, rather of the change to `SelectedRowsCount`. The BindingManager doesn't know they're related!

Also try using [Microsoft's naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx), `enableCollectionButton` should be `EnableCollectionButton`

Comment: Thanks very much!How could i oversee that?!!! I should go oftener for a walk!!Haha! And yes you 're about the naming conventions (usually i do keep the conventions)! Thanks very much again